# Why sometimes when I check whether a character is a digit by method isDigit in java, I get error?

Tags: java, methods

If I have

```
Character.isDigit('53')
```

I get error

but if I have:

```
Character.isDigit('5')
```

I get a boolean value of TRUE.

Why is that so?

Comment: if you want to check is 53 number or not look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java

Answer (score 3):

`'5'` is a character. `'53'` is not a character.

Or, to look at it in terms of strings, `"5"` is a string with one character in it (`'5'`), and `"53"` is a string with two characters in it (`'5'`, `'3'`).

Answer (score 0):

A character is a **single** symbol. This means that '5' is a character, but since '53' has two symbols, it is **not** a character.

Answer (score 0):

'5' and '53' both represent as a string where first contain a character and second contain two character.